# How to do chomp a Perl array without using foreach?

Tags: perl

How to do chomp the array without using a foreach?

```
 @array = ( " adfasdas 
", "asdas " , "23232 

",
"ads as" ; 

chomp (@array);
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can run this from your command line, and it will explain the capabilities of `chomp` or any other command: `perldoc -f chomp`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Exactly like that.

```
chomp @list;
```

['perldoc -f chomp'](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) for more info.

Answer (score 9):

Exactly how you're doing it.

```
chomp( @array );
```

Will chomp every element in the array.